# Upgrade redis from v2 to v4 on Windows causes Rails connection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, redis

## Background

My dev environment is Windows, Rails cache_store worked fine for redis V2.

I am implementing ActiveJob with sidekiq, which required redis >= v3

I installed Redis for Windows from [GitHub](https://github.com/tporadowski/redis/releases), I tried both V4 and V5.

## Windows setup

Ran the installation .msi file

After install and re-boot, checked the redis-cli and connected and tested fine.

## Rail setup

from config/environments/development.rb

```
  config.cache_store                = :redis_cache_store, { url: 'redis://localhost:6379/0' }
```

## Rails console

```
>> Rails.cache 
=> #<ActiveSupport::Cache::RedisCacheStore options={:namespace=>nil, :compress=>true, :compress_threshold=>1024, :expires_in=>nil, :race_condition_ttl=>nil} redis=#<Redis client v4.2.5 for redis://localhost:6379/0>>
>> Rails.cache.redis.connected?
=> false
>> t = Rails.cache.fetch('test') { 'T' }
=> "T"

>> r = Redis.new 
=> #<Redis client v4.2.5 for redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0>
>> r.get 'test'
=> "123"
>> r.connected?
=> true
```

## Question

What am I doing wrong in my config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Changed development.rb to:

```
     config.cache_store                = :redis_cache_store, { url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0' }
```